# How to get the absolute sum of all negative value in a specific range from list in c#

Tags: c#

I have a space separated list of int like below:

```
1 -2 3 1 -8 3 -2 5
```

I need an absolute sum of a specific range of that list i.e. from 4th index to 6th index. The result will be 10(from abs(-8-2)).

I can get the perfect result by using below code:

```
List<int> _subList = new List<int>();
string _input = Console.ReadLine();
List<int> _list = _input.Split(' ').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToList<int>();
var k =Math.Abs(_list.GetRange(3, 3).Where(x=>x<0).Sum());
Console.WriteLine(k);
```

But is there any way to do it without using Linq?

Comment: If you want help with your homework, please [edit] your question to show what you've come up with so far, and explain why it isn't working the way you expected it to. See also [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 2):

This is a great use case for LINQ extension methods.

1. split the string to get the constituent integer strings
2. skip to start offset
3. take desired element count (endOffset - startOffset + 1)
4. convert string values to integers via projection
5. filter for negative values
6. project negation
7. aggregate the sum

.

```
string input = "...";
var startOffset = 4;
var endOffset = 6;

var absSum = input.Split(' ')
    .Skip(startOffset)
    .Take(endOffset - startOffset + 1)
    .Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s))
    .Where(i => 0 > i)
    .Select(i => -i)
    .Sum();
```

Without LINQ extension methods:

```
    var targetElements = input.Split(' ')
        //.Skip(startOffset).Task(endOffset - startOffset + 1)
        .AsSpan(startOffset, endOffset - startOffset + 1);
    
    var absSum = 0;
    
    foreach(var element in targetElements)
    {
        //.Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s))
        var i = Convert.ToInt32(element);
        
        //.Where(i => 0 > i)
        if( 0 > i )
        {
            //.Sum()
            absSum += i;
        }
    }
    
    // we know sum is negative so negate for absolute value
    absSum = -absSum;
```

Comment: and if i want to take the negative should i add .Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)<0)?

Comment: you can use the `Where` method to filter the stream of data eg. `.Where(i => 0 > i)` if you only want to sum negative numbers over your target range (you would add this b/t the two `Select` invocations)

Answer (score 2):

> But is there any way to do it without using Linq?

```
List<int> data = new List<int>() { 1, -2, 3, 1, -8, 3, -2, 5 };

long sum = 0;

var minIndex = 4;
var maxIndex = 6;

for (int i = minIndex; i <= maxIndex && i < data.Count; i++)
{
    if (data[i] < 0)
    {
        sum -= data[i];
    }
}
```

Above is using a for loop with the appropriate indices to get the values out, and using `-` rather than `+` and `Abs` to get the output you expect.

If you explicitly need the string parsing:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();

var data = input?.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries | StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries) ?? Array.Empty<string>();

long sum = 0;

var minIndex = 4;
var maxIndex = 6;

for (int i = minIndex; i <= maxIndex && i < data.Length; i++)
{
    if (int.TryParse(data[i], out var val) && val < 0)
    {
        sum -= val;
    }
}
```

Note you need to use `?.` with the `Split` to handle `Console.ReadLine` returning `null`. And `StringSplitOptions` simplifies the trimming of whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<int> _subList = new List<int>();//1
            string _input = Console.ReadLine();//2
            List<int> _list = _input.Split(' ')//3
            .Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n))//4
            .ToList<int>();//5
            var k =Math.Abs(_list.GetRange(3, 3)//6 
            .Where(x=>x<0).Sum());//7
            Console.WriteLine(k);
```

I think code below is right

- In //1 creates empty List
- In //2 read space as string
- In //3 getting numbers to int List
- In //4 Iterating and converting to numbers from string to int
- In //5 get All as List in type int
- In //6 I think Math.abs clear,GetRange(3,3) is same begin from range in math (3,3+3] thats 4,5,6
- In //7 Sum() for getting sum

Comment: Two small suggestions. a) Don't use _ at the start of variable names. b) Consider that `ReadLine` might return `null`.

Comment: Also consider removing `_subList`.

Answer (score -1):

```
List<int> _subList = new List<int>();
string _input = Console.ReadLine();
List<int> _list = _input.Split(' ').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToList<int>();
var k =Math.Abs(_list.GetRange(3, 3).Where(x=>x<0).Sum());
Console.WriteLine(k);
```

Here `_list.GetRange(3, 3)` will  create the sublist
and then `Where(x=>x<0).Sum()` pick the negative values and sum it up
and ulimately `Math.Abs()` will give the absolute value

But here i have used *System.Linq*; If anyone can provide with better solution other than manual looping would be appriciated

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it fixes the problem, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Comment: How do "code only" answers help anyone?